# How this program has this output In C

Tags: c

i have a piece of code in C .But i am not able to understand its output

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{

char a1[20];
char a2[30];
char a3[40];
scanf("%s",&a1);
gets(a2);
fgets(a3,sizeof(a3),stdin);
printf("%d,%d,%d\n",strlen(a1),strlen(a2),strlen(a3));
 }
```

When i enter my input like

```
 amit
 singh
```

output comes out to be 4,0,6 and fgets doest not allow me to enter any string ,i am able to enter only 2 inputs?

Comment: `scanf` leaves `\n` in `stdin`.

Comment: OK then output should be 4,1,6.Is n't it

Comment: `gets()` reads `stdin` into given character string until a newline character is found or end-of-file occurs. therefore the `zero` length

Comment: no, strlen doesn't count the \n. just try to print a1,a2,a3. it would be more logic as 4,0,5.

Comment: So what you want to say @Prince is when i press enter after amit it will go in to stdin buffer , gets see the \n and read it as zero character and then fgets read the string

Comment: @RoeeGavirel printf("%u\n",strlen("\n")) // prints '1'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. input is `"amit\nsingh\n"`
2. the `scanf` consumes "amit" (and writes that into `a1`)
3. the `gets` consumes "\n" (and writes empty string to `a2`)
4. the `fgets` consumes "singh\n" (which it writes to `a3`)

The output is correct.

Do not **EVER** use `gets`!

1. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html
2. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gets.html
3. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html

Comment: why it gets writes empty string to a2?

Comment: `a2` gets an empty string because that is how `gets` works (**do not use `gets` in the future**): *ignoring end-of-file error condition* it reads up to and including a newline and writes everything **except** the newline to the array.

Answer (score 2):

scanf leaves a '\n' in the stream which is read by gets.
gets doesn't count \n in the length. Hence you get a 0 there.
Then your fgets reads "singh" and as it does take into account the newline character, it outputs 6.

Have a look at the following references for better understanding:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/gets/

Comment: One doubt @krammer fgets read singh with \n character.but which \n character ,i meant is it take \n from end of singh??

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar yes. as the previous \n (from scanf) has already been consumed by gets.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf()` takes *amit* and stores it in array `a1`.

Since functions of the `scanf()` family leave the newline character in the input buffer and `gets()` reads up to a *newline* character (which it finds immediately), it stores an empty string into `a2`.

So the call to `fgets()` reads *singh* into `a3`. `fgets()` puts also the newline character into the target variable - this is why you see 6 characters as string length for `a3`.

Since there are no more input commands, no 3rd line is read.

Comment: What is target variable here??

Comment: its the variable where the value will be put in i.e. a3